# React native reuqest with client certificate

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, client-certificates

I need to call the REST Api from my react-native application using client certificate. Basicaly I need to do http request and stick the certificate located on file system to it, so the server knows its me. I realy tried to find any example of this but wasnt able to. Can someone provide me with such example or atleast point me somewhere where I can find it?

Thank you very much!